# How to get each elements in an array between some interval

Tags: r

In matlab, for example. I would like to choose elements in an array this way

```
Array[1:2:end]
```

which choose elements every 2 intervals.

I am just wondering how to do exactly the same thing in R

Comment: Use `seq` to generate your interval?

Comment: `Array[c(TRUE, FALSE)]` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work `Array[seq(1,length(Array),2)]`